# Matrix Derivative Should be A prime or simply A?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, derivatives

I was doing exercise 1 from [this problem set](http://www.econ.cam.ac.uk/graduate/mphil/premath/Linear_Algebra_ps_3.pdf).

It asks us to prove that d(ax)/d(x) = a. However, on one of my class handout it says that:

d(a'x)=a'dx, therefore d(a'x)/dx = a'.

**It seems that they are contradicting each other. I was wondering which solution is correct and why?**

If you look at Jacobian matrix, it is d(fx)/dx', instead of d(fx)/dx. This suggests that it is taking a derivative regarding to a row vector.

**I was wondering when should I take derivative on a row vector and when should I take derivative on a column vector?**

Comment: The definition at the top of the problem set you linked suggests it must equal a'.  My guess is that question 1 is just being informal and not distinguishing between a' and a.

Comment: I think, according to the definition on the problem set, the problem is correct: the derivative should be $a$, not $a'$, since the derivative should have the same "shape" (i.e. dimensions) as the input vector $x$.

Answer (score 0):

I think your confusion is when you say:

"d(a'x)=a'dx, therefore d(a'x)/dx = a'."

The first equation involves differential forms, and the second is a statement about derivatives. You can't just "divide by dx". This is a useful mnemonic trick in undergraduate calculus, but it is not rigorous, and technically not correct.

The first statement (involving differentials) is correct. Here's why: let's write $\mathbf{a} = (a_1,\dots,a_n)'$ and $\mathbf{x} = (x_1,\dots,x_n)'$. Then the "dot product" $a'x$ can be written as $\sum_i a_i x_i$. So the first formula you mention (with the differentials), says
$$ d\left( \sum_i a_i x_i \right) = \sum_i a_i \, dx_i $$
This is obviously true by the linearity of $d$.

However, the convention (as noted in the problem set you posted) is that $\frac{\partial f(\mathbf{x})}{\partial \mathbf{x}}$ has the same dimensions as the matrix $\mathbf{x}$, which in this example is a column vector. Since $\mathbf{a}$ is a column vector and $\mathbf{a}'$ is a row vector, the derivative should be $\mathbf{a}$, and *not* $\mathbf{a}'$.